# Argument passed must be an instance of PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Module\AdminModuleDataProvider

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i get this error after installing prestashop i cant access frontend

> FatalThrowableError
>
> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Addon\Module\ModuleRepository::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Module\AdminModuleDataProvider, null
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/html/store/src/Core/Addon/Module/ModuleManagerBuilder.php on
>   line 141

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to set write permission on app/config folder